# How to access express server session in nextjs api routes?

Tags: express, next.js

I am building my site with NextJs. I have a social login component where users can login via e.g. facebook Login. From the social login component (e.g. Facebook login) I get back user data (name, email) into my custom _app . So far so good.

With this user data, I want to create (or identify) an user on my headless wordpress backend. I want to use the Wordpress REST API for that. So I created an wordpress API restpoint which recieves user data, creates the user in wordpress if he is not existing yet, and then returns a JWT access token for calling other wordpress API restpoints where the user then can create some user specific data in my wordpress DB via my website.

What is the best approach to do this with Nextjs and a custom express server? My first idea was to use the new API Route feature and created a pages/api/test.js page like the example in the doc shows.

```
export default function handle(req, res) {
res.send({some:'json'})
}
```

So the whole flow starts in _app when getting the user data from the social login component. My first approach:

```
handleFBSocialLogin = (user) => {
//pesudo code:
//fetch("/api/test") with user data
}
```

When doing this my api/test.js is called and inside that i could then call my Wordpress API to get the token back, right?
But then i want to store the token server-side in my custom express server session, but how do i do that now?
And how do i read it from there in later requests to other wordpress API restpoints?

And - does that approach makes sense at all ?

Appreciate any input!